# Django multiple tests + setUp + migrations

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, python-unittest

I am really puzzled by this: I use #Django 1.11.2.  I have a couple of tests inside the same test class.  They (and the actual code) rely on data, that I inject using **migrations**.  In particular, I create some security groups.  Migrations work perfectly when run by `./manage.py migrate`.  They also seem to work just fine for the first test in the class.  However, when `setUp` is run for the second test, it complains that the group doesn't exist.  This is my setup function from a test class:

```
class MyDjangoTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # Every test needs access to the request factory.
        self.client = Client()
        self.password = 'top_secret'
        # ERROR: fails at this line in test_2 wit object not found exception, test_1 OK
        group: Group = Group.objects.get_by_natural_key("SomeGroup")

        self.user1: User = User.objects.create_user(
            username='john', email='john@…', password=self.password)
        self.user1.groups.add(group)
        self.user2: User = User.objects.create_user(
            username='jane', email='jane@…', password=self.password)
        self.user2.groups.add(group)

    def test_1(self):
        # Executes just fine
        doStuff()

    def test_2(self):
        # Throws an exception when fetching the group in setUp
        doMoreStuff()
```

Comment: I think I understand what's going on - django flush-es all data from the database between individual tests, so my groups are destroyed, by design one could say.  I will need to adjust for that in my test setup code.